# How to count columns of a model in pry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry

I want to count the number of columns of a model in a Rails project.

By running the command `show-model Company`, I can see all columns and their `has_many` relations. How can I count these columns?

In bash console, I can count by `ls -l | wc -l`. Is there a similar way to do like `show-model Company | .wc -l`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this while in pry:

```
Company.columns.size
```

This returns the number of elements within the resulting array of column objects for the table associated with the given class.

[Docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/columns/class)

Hope that helps!